# deserializeObject exception on WindowOperator

Tags: apache-flink

It's seem that the data in the `WindowOperator` can serialize successfully. however deserialize failed when the `taskmanager` restarted by `jobmanager`.

env: *state* 
backend: *hdfs*; 
jobmanager: *high-availability*

**Root exception:**

```
java.lang.Exception: Could not restore checkpointed state to operators and functions
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restoreStateLazy(StreamTask.java:414)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:208)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:584)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 00
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readBlockHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:2508)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.refill(ObjectInputStream.java:2543)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.read(ObjectInputStream.java:2615)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:387)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readInt(ObjectInputStream.java:2820)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readInt(ObjectInputStream.java:971)
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1158)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor29.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1893)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.deserializeObject(InstantiationUtil.java:294)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.operators.windowing.WindowOperator$Context.<init>(WindowOperator.java:446)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.operators.windowing.WindowOperator.restoreState(WindowOperator.java:621)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restoreStateLazy(StreamTask.java:406)
```

Comment: Could you provide a code example with which you were able to reproduce the problem? That would be really helpful :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same issue, when I run multiple flink application with the same custom window/trigger class reused.
(I don't know if it's your case)
But I add generated serialVersionUID in my different reused class and it's work fine now

Comment: How did you add it? Any reference?

Comment: I add it to my custom class, with my IDE plugins (I use Netbeans)